# Finding most likely purchases for a customer with list of purchases on different days

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm having trouble finding an efficient solution to this problem.
Lets say you have these purchases on different days with different brands.

```
String []  day1= {"Nike", "Adidas", "Croc"};
String []  day2= {"Adidas", "Croc", "Reebok"};
String []  day3= {"Croc", "Reebok", "Sketchers"};
```

You then have to print the most likely purchase for each brand.

```
For example:
Nike -> Adidas, Croc //Adidas and Croc appears most times with Nike
Adidas -> Croc //Croc appears most times with Adidas
Croc -> Adidas //Adidas appears most times with Croc
```

I've thought about a few options. Like utilizing a map to store the mapping between brands. But that would require traversal back through the map, and I think there is a more efficient algorithm for this.

Thank you

Comment: Try to code something first.

Comment: Take a look at Association Analysis and especially the Apriori algorithm.